# After creating folder on desktop - renaming or removing needs admin privileges?

Tags: finder, mojave, administrator, macos

Just now I created a folder on my desktop. It had the name "untitled folder". I wanted to change the name to something else, but got an alert that I needed admin rights. Removing the folder has the same effect.

I tried this several times, directly on the desktop and using the Finder. I checked the Info for the Desktop folder and all seemed OK. I have read and write access.

Creating a folder in the Documents folder works normally. System is macOS 10.14 Mojave.

What is this, and how do I correct it?

---

**Update**

As requested by Allan, the output of the ls-commands. I've copied the results for the Documents and Downloads folder for comparison, plus some files inside the Desktop folder, including the newly created "untitled" folder.

```
$ ls -la /Users/sprbrn
drwxr-x---+ 14 sprbrn  staff      448 Mar  5 13:37 Desktop
drwx------+ 47 sprbrn  staff     1504 Mar  5 13:04 Documents
drwx------+ 55 sprbrn  staff     1760 Mar  6 22:06 Downloads


$ ls -la /Users/sprbrn/Desktop
drwxr-x---+ 14 sprbrn  staff   448 Mar  5 13:37 .
drwx------+ 82 sprbrn  staff  2624 Feb 10 20:29 ..
-rw-r-----   1 sprbrn  staff  8196 Mar  5 13:39 .DS_Store
-rw-r-----   1 sprbrn  staff     0 Aug 14  2017 .localized
drwxr-xr-x   2 sprbrn  staff    64 Mar  5 13:37 untitled folder
```

Here I show the output for the Desktop folder from the first command and `.` folder from the second command next to eachother.

```
drwxr-x---+ 14 sprbrn  staff      448 Mar  5 13:37 Desktop
drwxr-x---+ 14 sprbrn  staff      448 Mar  5 13:37 .
```

I don't see any difference in the output, and I have no idea what else to look for.

Comment: Navigate to the desktop "the long way" Open Macintosh HD, then Users/yourname/ & select the desktop folder. Get Info. What does it say for Sharing & Permissions? Should be (me) Read & Write, Everyone No access.

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two methods. I do see a difference with other folders, the Desktop folder having a rights entry for Staff (read only). The other folders don't have that. I don't see how that would change things.

Comment: Is this your computer?  If so, you should have administrator rights when you log on.

Comment: Yes this is my computer. And of course I have administrator's rights, but not on my account. I have a separate admin account and prefer it that way.

Comment: @Allan, and then what?

Comment: @Allan, see the update

Comment: Ok.  So far the permissions seem correct.  Now, in *Terminal*, navigate to your desktop (`cd /Users/sprbrn`) and create, then delete a file (`touch testfile.txt`; `rm testfile.txt`)

Comment: OK, I can do that, as well as create and delete a folder with `mkdir`.

Comment: Hi @Allan, what does your suggestion try to prove? How to proceed from here?

Comment: We're trying to narrow down whether it's an underlying UNIX issue or a Finder issue.  Now, create another user (just for testing), log in and attempt to replicate the problem.

Comment: I don't know what has changed, but suddenly I can rename and delete folders at the desktop. So problem solved somehow?